# Query range site URL is missing or is invalid

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, administration, site, delete

I want de delete a modern sharepoint site. but I get the message:

> Query range site ULR is missing or is invalid

What can I do about this so I can delete the site?

Comment: How are you deleting the site, from browser or other way (PowerShell, REST API, Power automate, etc.)?

Comment: Hi, from the browser

Comment: Are there any subsites under this site?

Comment: No there are no subsites

Comment: So the site URL still can be accessed now? Also have a try to change a browser.

Comment: Yes i still can access my Sharepoint site that i have created. But not able to delete it. Even with another browser